# Converting battery capacity from Ah to Wh: Which voltage should be used?

Tags: voltage, batteries, watts, conversion, ampere-hour

I need to convert the battery capacity from ampere-hours to be Watt hours.

I know that \$P=VI\$ in Watts, however I'm unsure of which voltage I will need to use in order to use this relation; there seem to be a lot of different voltages listed in battery data sheet.

For example, with [these batteries (Sunica+)](http://www.saftbatteries.com/battery-search/sunicaplus) the following specs are listed in the data sheets, and these are just some of many related to voltage:

- float 1.5 V/cell
- boast 1.6 V/cell
- battery system 12/24/48 V
- Nominal Capacity 120 - 1.0 V Ah
- final voltage 1.14-1.20 V
- ...

So to someone fairly inexperienced in the technical aspects of batteries, simply saying 'V*mAh/1000' is fairly meaningless. Should you use the battery system (12/24 etc) or is it one of the others times the number of cells, or none of these?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You always want to use the average discharge voltage for the battery. For NiCd (the link is to a NiCd standby battery), I believe 1.2V/cell is the typically used value when computing Wh. So if it is 120 Ah, you would have 144 Wh.

Comment: And this would be 144 Wh/cell then right? So I would times this by x-number of cells in the pack?@mkeith

Comment: @Maitiu - you got it. Another way to look at it is, if each cell can put out 100 amps for 1 hour, a pack of n cells can put out 100 amps for one hour, but at n times the voltage. So the volts times current works the same way, just with different voltages.